# Why the ip proxy function of python requests lib doesn't work?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I was creating some web spider project with python3 which needs to change ip frequently. The lib I use to get/post requests is "requests". The official document mentioned that add `proxies=ip #ip={'http':'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx'}` with `get/post` method to use ip proxy.

Btw, suggest you guys can use the free api from the proxy website:gimmeproxy.com it's so good :)

I found my spider still banned by target website, then I write a function to test whether the `proxies=ip` works:

```
def test():
    ip=get_proxy("US")
    url='https://api.ipify.org?format=json'
    res=s.get(url,proxies=ip,verify=True)
    dic=json.loads(res.text)
    print(dic["ip"])
```

This website will return your current ip, I found the `proxies=ip`doesn't work....

**Anyone meet the same situation before?? Or I did something wrong??**

Thanks for read and answer :)